# C# MongoDB tries to convert enum:uint32 to int32 and crashes

Tags: c#, mongodb, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum MyEnum : uint
    {
        ValueA = 1233104067,
        ValueB= 1119849093,
        ValueC= 2726580491
}
```

Whenever I create some class with this enum and try to store it into the database.
 For example

```
class MyClass {
    public MyEnum newValue = MyEnum.ValueC;
}
```

It will crash the program with this error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
   at System.Convert.ThrowInt32OverflowException()
   at System.UInt32.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumSerializer`1.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TEnum value)
```

It tries to convert uint values to int, but they are too big and it throws exception.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I created a JIRA issue for that and will provide a PR that fixes this behaviour: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2127

Comment: PR: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/pull/310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB stores data as BSON, which [doesn't have unsigned integer types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

You have three options:

1. Annotate your unsigned types.

   If using driver v2.4.3 or earlier:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32, AllowOverflow = true)]
       public MyEnum Value1 = MyEnum.ValueC;

       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32, AllowOverflow = true)]
       public uint Value2 = uint.MaxValue;
   }
   ```

   Unfortunately the serializer in driver v2.4.4 and later doesn't respect 
   `AllowOverflow`, throwing an exception anyway(tested and 
   confirmed, thanks to dnickless for pointing this out). Here's a workaround 
   (at the expense of some wasted space):

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]
       public MyEnum Value1 = MyEnum.ValueC;

       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]
       public uint Value2 = uint.MaxValue;
   }
   ```
2. Use signed types and convert where appropriate.

   ```
   // Defaults to int.
   public enum MyEnum
   {
       ValueA = 1233104067,
       ValueB = 1119849093,
       ValueC = unchecked((int)2726580491)
   }

   // Usage.
   uint a = (uint)MyEnum.ValueA;
   uint b = (uint)MyEnum.ValueB;
   uint c = unchecked((uint)MyEnum.ValueC);
   uint d = (uint)document["MyProperty"].AsInt32; // Reading from a BsonDocument.
   ```
3. Serialize manually([UInt32Serializer](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Serializers_UInt32Serializer.htm), [UInt64Serializer](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Serializers_UInt64Serializer.htm), etc).

Comment: #1 does not work (also it would seem more reasonable to annotate the fields as BsonType.Int64 instead of letting them overflow). The reason for that being that the EnumSerializer won't respect the AllowOverflow attribute as of v2.4.4.